# Dotted input's border and password look strange in IE and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

In IE8 when field is focused it looks dotted. Also, when typing in password field it shows strange symblos(this bug is also in Chrome, but in others look good).

IE screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2b5mpjbyrfn8fh/ie_focused.png

Chrome screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zi8eq7zposn6c9/chrome.png

CSS:

```
.field input {
font-size: 14px;
border: 1px solid rgba(98,141, 40, 0.5);
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
border-radius:5px;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);

}

.field input:focus{
font-size: 14px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
border: 1px solid rgb(98,141, 40);
border-radius:5px;
}
```

**ADDING HTML FORM**

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="login" id="new_user" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="U+7u2UTO/3LS4dHOL21PgMpln5qZfrEWfwvnN/fxN6A="></div>
<div class="field2">

  <label for="user_email">E-mail Adress</label>
  <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="">
</div>

  <div class="field2">
    <label for="user_password">Password</label>
     <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password"> 
</div>
```

Where could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the font, change the font on your password box:

```
#user_password {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey now clear the default outline

as like this

```
.field input:focus{
outline:0;
}
```

Comment: it is worked for border. thanks. but what about strange view of password ?